# How to use jQuery to postpone setting event listeners until after ajax call and rendering has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm familiar with Underscore's `_.defer` function.  How can I recreate this with jQuery?

I am performing an ajax call, appending `divs` from the response of that call into the DOM, but the problem is, I need to set set event listeners on those newly created `divs`, yet I have to wait until they are rendered.  How can I do this?

```
$.getJSON( mAPI, function( m ) {
   $(m.items).each(function(item) {
       $('#items-container').append('<div class="item">' + item + '</div>');
   });
}):

$( ".item" ).click(function(e) {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$("#items-container").on("click", ".item", function (e) {
    alert("Handler for .click() called");
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is probably to delegate the events to the container using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$('#items-container').on('click', '.item', function (e) {
    alert('Handler for .click() called');
});
```

*Note:* You would only need to attach this event handler once, not after every AJAX request. (Thanks [@Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570837/how-to-use-jquery-to-postpone-setting-event-listeners-until-after-ajax-call-and#comment29043753_19570862))

Comment: Note also, this would only need to happen once rather than every time that getJSON request is made.

Comment: @KevinB: That's probably a good thing to clarify, thanks. Updated my answer.